# Mocking Static Methods in PHP

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, static-methods

My goal is to be able to write unit tests for static methods that advocate:

1. Maintainability - I want the code to be as easy to follow, understand, and debug over time.
2. Performance - I'd like the speed of our tests not to suffer due to our technical debt if possible.

Constraints: We cannot refactor the static method to be an instance method. That would be first thing I would probably suggest, but I'm looking for an options/alternatives and opinions.

Testing static methods is a bit of a pain. There was a time that we could do this with phpunit. Mockery supports a means to test [static methods](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html) through [aliasing](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#creating-test-doubles-aliasing), but its not recommended. I've found that running these types of tests can be very slow. (hence the Goal #2).

Unfortunately, if you have a fair amount of code that relies on other code using static methods, you are at mercy of your own debt. There are some techniques using `call_user_func`(https://medium.com/@nihon_rafy/how-to-mock-static-methods-for-unit-tests-in-php-18b2a11458d0) and `forward_static_call_array()` (http://miljar.github.io/blog/2014/01/29/phpunit-testing-static-calls/), but I find myself having difficulty following this code.

I want to provide an alternative dynamic option, similar to the above.

```
class LegacyClass {
    public static function staticMethod($a, $b, $c) {
        return QueryBuilder::where($a, $b, $c)->getAll();
    }

}

class ClassToTest {
    public function test($a, $b, $c) {
        return LegacyClass::staticMethod($a+1, $b+2, $c+3);

}
```

changes to this =>

```
class LegacyClass {
    public static function staticMethod($a, $b, $c) {
        return QueryBuilder::where($a, $b, $c)->getAll();
    }

}

class ClassToTest{
    // @var string fully qualified class name
    private $legacyClass = LegacyClass::class;
    public function test($a, $b, $c) {
        return {$this->legacyClass}::staticMethod($a+1, $b+2, $c+3);

}
```

Now, with the above, we can mock the `LegacyClass`, get the class name of that mock, and use `Reflection` to set the private `$legacyClass` variable.

With that, my questions:

1. Which of the options above present the most maintainable solution?
2. Are there any better alternatives that meet the stated goals? (If so, I can append)

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I have been going back to very often is creating a "man-in-the-middle"-class. I use this for static function calls but also for cases where a `new Object();` was created in the middle of the code.

In essence you are simply moving the problem somewhere else which might not look like a good solution but you make your `ClassToTest` easily testable by moving one line away.

So in short; I would make a new class (`StaticFunctionCallerClass`). This class would have one function that has one line.

```
class StaticFunctionCallerClass {
    public function test($a, $b, $c) {
        return LegacyClass::staticMethod($a+1, $b+2, $c+3);

}
```

Now you can instantiate this class in your `ClassToTest` (and therefore mock it in the test). So you can test all the logic around it and even test that your new `StaticFunctionCallerClass` is also called with the right information.

The drawback here is that it leaves your new `StaticFunctionCallerClass` with the line of hard to test code. You could call this class in your `LegacyClassTest` to test if the call is done correctly though, which is maybe not a very clean option but it does get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and approach Dirk. That is definitely another solution I hadn't considered. I think that could add some overhead long term, but it does get the job done. That does spark another idea - I wonder if there was a clean/performant approach to the above using php7s anonymous classes